# Create data source for Weblogic 12.2.1.3 in offline mode

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c, wlst

I want to create Weblogic data source using WLST in offline mode and I'm getting error when I want to create Properties:

```
create('my_Prop','Properties')
```

Here is the entire script:

```
readDomain('C:\\weblogic12213\\user_projects\\domains\\myDomain')
cd('/')
create('myJDBC', 'JDBCSystemResource')
cd('/JDBCSystemResource/myJDBC')
set('Target','myApp')
cd('/JDBCSystemResource/myJDBC/JdbcResource/myJDBC')
cmo.setName('myJDBC')

create('myJDBC','JDBCDataSourceParams')
cd('JDBCDataSourceParams/myJDBC')
set('JNDIName', java.lang.String('jdbc.myJDBC'))
set('GlobalTransactionsProtocol', java.lang.String('OnePhaseCommit'))

cd('/JDBCSystemResource/myJDBC/JdbcResource/myJDBC')
create('myJDBC','JDBCDriverParams')
cd('JDBCDriverParams/myJDBC')
set('DriverName','weblogic.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver')
set('URL','jdbc:weblogic:sqlserver://localhost:1433;allowPortWithNamedInstance=true')
set('PasswordEncrypted', 'myPassword')
set('UseXADataSourceInterface', 'false')

create('my_Prop','Properties')
cd('Properties/myJDBC')
create('user','Property')
cd('Property/user')
set('Value', 'myUser')

cd('/JDBCSystemResource/myJDBC/JdbcResource/myJDBC')
create('myJDBC','JDBCConnectionPoolParams')
cd('JDBCConnectionPoolParams/myJDBC')
set('TestTableName','SQL SELECT 1')
updateDomain()
closeDomain()
exit()
```

This error appears:

```
com.oracle.cie.domain.script.jython.WLSTException: Could not create generic operation:Properties
@com.oracle.cie.domain.operation.OperationBuilder.createConfigOperation(OperationBuilder.java:342)
at com.oracle.cie.domain.script.jython.CommandExceptionHandler.handleException(CommandExceptionHandler.java:69)
at com.oracle.cie.domain.script.jython.WLScriptContext.handleException(WLScriptContext.java:2983)
```

---

Does anybody have any idea please?

Comment: Can you post the entire scrit ?

Comment: Just added the entire script. Thanks.

Comment: You are trying to create properties from the wrong mbean. Try this :  
`cd('/JDBCSystemResource/myJDBC/JdbcResource/myJDBC')  
create('connectionPoolParams', 'JDBCConnectionPoolParams')  
cd('/JDBCSystemResource/myJDBC/JdbcResource/myJDBC/JDBCConnectionPoolParams/NO_NAME_0')  

create('Properties', 'Properties')`

Comment: Still getting same error:
`wls:/offline/domain_devl/JDBCSystemResource/myJDBC/JdbcResource/myJDBC/JDBCConnectionPoolParams/NO_NAME_0>create('Properties', 'Properties')
Error: create() failed. Do dumpStack() to see details.`

Comment: What does the DumpStack() say  ?

Comment: `com.oracle.cie.domain.script.jython.WLSTException: Could not create generic operation:Properties
 @com.oracle.cie.domain.operation.OperationBuilder.createConfigOperation(OperationBuilder.java:342)
        at com.oracle.cie.domain.script.jython.CommandExceptionHandler.handleException(CommandExceptionHandler.java:69)
        at com.oracle.cie.domain.script.jython.WLScriptContext.handleException(WLScriptContext.java:2983)
        at com.oracle.cie.domain.script.jython.WLScriptContext.create(WLScriptContext.java:1526)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)...`

Comment: sorry, i made a mistake in my previous comment :   cd('/JDBCSystemResources/myJDBC/JdbcResource/myJDBC')  create('dbParams','JDBCDriverParams')  cd('JDBCDriverParams/NO_NAME_0')    dbProps = create('props','Properties')

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you already found the solution. This works for me without errors.

```
# cd into the already created driver params

cd('/JDBCSystemResource/myJDBC/JdbcResource/myJDBC/JDBCDriverParams/NO_NAME_0')
create('properties','Properties')
cd('Properties/NO_NAME_0')
create('property','Property')
cd('Property/property')
set("Key", "key")
set("Value", "value")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"""
This script configures a JDBC data source as a System Module and deploys it
to the server
"""
url='t3://' + sys.argv[1] + ':' + sys.argv[2]
username = sys.argv[3]
password = sys.argv[4]

connect(username,password,url)
edit()

# Change these names as necessary
dsname="myJDBCDataSource"
server=sys.argv[5]
cd("Servers/"+server)
target=cmo
cd("../..")

startEdit()
# start creation
print 'Creating JDBCSystemResource with name '+dsname
jdbcSR = create(dsname,"JDBCSystemResource")
theJDBCResource = jdbcSR.getJDBCResource()
theJDBCResource.setName("myJDBCDataSource")

connectionPoolParams = theJDBCResource.getJDBCConnectionPoolParams()
connectionPoolParams.setConnectionReserveTimeoutSeconds(25)
connectionPoolParams.setMaxCapacity(100)
connectionPoolParams.setTestTableName("SYSTABLES")

dsParams = theJDBCResource.getJDBCDataSourceParams()
dsParams.addJNDIName("ds.myJDBCDataSource")

driverParams = theJDBCResource.getJDBCDriverParams()
driverParams.setUrl("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/examples;create=true")
driverParams.setDriverName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientXADataSource")
# driverParams.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@my-oracle-server:my-oracle-server-port:my-oracle-sid")
# driverParams.setDriverName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")

driverParams.setPassword("examples")
# driverParams.setLoginDelaySeconds(60)
driverProperties = driverParams.getProperties()

proper = driverProperties.createProperty("user")
#proper.setName("user")
proper.setValue("examples")

proper1 = driverProperties.createProperty("DatabaseName")
#proper1.setName("DatabaseName")
proper1.setValue("examples")

jdbcSR.addTarget(target)

save()
activate(block="true")

print 'Done configuring the data source'`enter code here`
```